# Underscore sortBy

Tags: sorting, underscore.js

```
 var array =  [{"id":"0", "stopDate":null},
               {"id":"1", "stopDate":"10/06/2014"},
               {"id":"2", "stopDate":null},
               {"id":"3", "stopDate":"09/06/2014"}];
```

I have array of objects as above and want to sort by stop date using underscore. I am using following function to do so.

```
_.sortBy(array, "stopDate"); // asc
_.sortBy(array, "stopDate").reverse(); //desc
```

Above method sorts the date value properly but ignores null. So the output for asc is coming out to be

```
var actual=  [{"id":"0", "stopDate":null},
              {"id":"3", "stopDate":"09/06/2014"},
              {"id":"2", "stopDate":null},
              {"id":"1", "stopDate":"10/06/2014"}];
```

But I am expecting null to be grouped together and should appear one after other.

```
var expected=  [{"id":"0", "stopDate":null},
                {"id":"2", "stopDate":null},
                {"id":"3","stopDate":"09/06/2014" },
                {"id":"1", "stopDate":"10/06/2014"}];
```

Comment: When I ran your code I got the "expected" output, i.e. 0, 2, 3, 1.

Comment: Are those `stopDate` values strings or Dates? If they're strings then you really should reformat them to ISO 8601 format so that they compare properly.

Comment: @Jordan: Sheer luck, caused by the sort implementation of your browser :-)

Comment: @Bergi Actually because the original question was different (OP had `"--"` instead of `null`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Above method sorts the date value properly

Not really. A lexical string comparison on the format `DD/MM/YYYY` hardly will return the expected results.

> but ignores "--"

There are no `"--"` values in your objects, there only are `null` values. And since `null` values are *neither greater nor smaller* than (non-numeric) strings (you can try in console, it always yields `false`), they are considered equal - which does however make an [inconsistent comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24080786/1048572).

What you should do instead is parse those date strings into properly comparable timestamps, and the `null` values into either `-Infinity` or `+Infinity` so that they compare with the timestamps as expected:

```
_.sortBy(array, function(d) {
    if (d.stopDate == null) return -Infinity;
    var parts = d.stopDate.split("/");
    return (new Date(+parts[2], parts[1]-1, +parts[0])).getTime();
});
```